# Derivative of an integral over a varying domain

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

Consider the function $$H(\alpha) = \int_{\Omega(\alpha)} h(\alpha,x) dx,$$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\Omega(\alpha)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a domain that varies continuously with $\alpha$. Is there a way to write $\frac{\partial H}{\partial\alpha}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should look at [this pdf](https://teaching.ust.hk/~mech221/Notes/LeibnizsRule.pdf), chapter A.2.

Comment: Great, I think this solves it. What is the reference?